# xmlbeans 5.0.0 saxon for xpath

Tags: xpath, saxon, xmlbeans

I'm trying to upgrade from xmlbeans 3.1.0 to 5.0.0 using saxon HE 9.9.1-7. Previously, instead of saxon we configured Jaxen for xpath using src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.PathDelegate.SelectPathInterface.

I've encountered a couple of problems:

1. 5.0.0 removed PathDelegate.SelectPathInterface. It now uses org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpath.Path. I've tried to configure a different xpath engine by making appropriate changes in META-INF/services but it didn't work (i.e. xmlbeans still uses saxon). How can I replace saxon?
2. How do can I configure the namespace-to-URI mappings? In the call stack below, the namespaceMap passed to the constructor is null or empty:

```
SaxonXPath(String path, String contextVar, Map<String, String> namespaceMap)
    getCompiledPathSaxon(String, String, Map<String, String>)
        execute(Cur, XmlOptions)
        getCompiledPath(String, XmlOptions, String)
```

As a result:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Namespace prefix 'table' has not been declared
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:315)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:272)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.makeStructuredQName(XPathParser.java:3796)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.makeNameTest(XPathParser.java:3848)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseNodeTest(XPathParser.java:2757)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(XPathParser.java:2253)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:2076)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRemainingPath(XPathParser.java:2035)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression(XPathParser.java:1940)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression(XPathParser.java:1971)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1824)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle(XPathParser.java:753)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExpression(XPathParser.java:660)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:522)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionTool.make(ExpressionTool.java:107)
        at net.sf.saxon.sxpath.XPathEvaluator.createExpression(XPathEvaluator.java:134)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpath.saxon.SaxonXPath.selectNodes(SaxonXPath.java:109)
...
```

Comment: Sorry you haven't had an answer here. I'm afraid it's a question about xmlbeans, not really about Saxon, so there's not much that we at Saxonica can do to help.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't watched the xmlbeans tag on SO. I've disabled XPath extension mechanism, as most built-in extensions are obsolete.
Have you tried the `.selectPath("declare namespace xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xs:schema")`syntax?